# opacidad de un background sin afectar otros con css

Tags: css, html5, estilos

quisiera saber como le puedo cambiar la opacidad del fondo del header sin cambiar la opacidad de los contenidos dentro
eh buscado por varios sitios y no puedo encontrar como resolverlo si pueden ayudarme estaría agradecido

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    width:100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: url(/img/colorFondo.jpg);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.ancho{
    width: 80%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo{
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo p img{
    width: 32%;
}

nav{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: rale;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: aqua;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: rale;
    src: url(/fonts/Raleway/static/Raleway-Regular.ttf);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="ancho">
            <div class="logo">
                <p><img src="/img/logoCopaNavideña.jpg" alt="logo" srcset=""></p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CRONOGRAMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="zona1">

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

GRACIAS POR EL INTENTO
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

Comment: Exactamente a qué objeto le querés dar una opacidad? A la imagen de fondo o un fondo sólido opaco?

Answer (score 0):

Para esto se puede usar los pseudoelementos **::before** antes, y **::after** que es después.

En éste caso use `:before` para colocar ahí la imagen de fondo. Es aquí que se puede usar con libertad una opacidad, ya sea con un fondo de color sólido o una imágen:

```
header:before {
 content: "";
 background: url(/img/colorFondo.jpg); 
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Suponiendo que la imagen de fondo sea una imagen (y no de un color sólido) se puede agregar un color de fondo al header, y esto para que convine el

- color de fondo del header
- Imagen de fondo del `::before`
- opacidad del `::before`

Lo cual queda así:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{ 
 position: relative;
 width:100%; 
 height: 70px;  
 background-color: violet; /* opcional */
} 

header:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch); 
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

.ancho{
    width: 80%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo{
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo p img{
    width: 32%;
}

nav{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: rale;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: aqua;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: rale;
    src: url(/fonts/Raleway/static/Raleway-Regular.ttf);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="ancho">
            <div class="logo">
                <p><img src="/img/logoCopaNavideña.jpg" alt="logo" srcset=""></p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">CRONOGRAMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GRUPO 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="zona1">

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```